# UIViewAnimation Flip not working

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewanimation

In a UIView subclass I have this:

```
self.frontImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"front"]];
self.backImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back"]];
[self addSubview:self.backImageView];


[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                     animations:^{
                         [self.backImageView removeFromSuperview];
                         [self addSubview:self.frontImageView];}

                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         //nothing
                     }];
```

But I don't get the flip animation. The front image view just appears immediately. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making a silly mistake using

```
animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:
```

instead of

```
transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:
```

Your code should be:

```
[UIView transitionFromView:backImageView
                    toView:frontImageView
                  duration:0.5
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                    // animation completed
                }];
```